# 18.04: cp only copies first 263 MB of files to USB

Tags: copy, usb-drive, fat32

I noticed that my computer (`GNOME` desktop environment) somehow cannot handle copying files larger than 275775488 B (263 MB) to my USB stick. I tried copying the files several times and the files smaller than 263 MB always worked well, but when I tried copying a larger file, the copying process didn't show any progress when the file reaches 275775488 B. I tried copying with `$ cp -r` in one command, `cp` within a `BASH` script iterating over the files and the "clicky" way with `nautilus`.
I always get the same result: When a file larger than 275775488 B is copied, the first 275775488 B are copied as expected. Then, neither the progress increases nor I can abort copying and/or unmount the USB stick.
It seems that the process somehow freezed at this point.

Unfortunately, the USB stick is also slow somehow, maybe because I had to format the USB stick as `FAT` for I'm not the default user and I somehow cannot format the USB stick as `ext4` (by using `$ gnome-disks`).

I also hardly can use a smaller USB stick than the one I'm using because copying all the files would become quite complicated then.

Would it be a solution to format the USB stick in a way that `gid` and `uid` would be different?

**EDIT**

```
nepumuk@shared:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        1.6G         12G        364M        1.9G         13G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
nepumuk@shared:~$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
nepumuk@shared:~$ uname -a
Linux shared 5.3.0-28-generic #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 06:14:09 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Are you able to format the flash drive as exFAT?

Comment: Is your Ubuntu a 32-bit or 64-bit system? Please check with `uname -a` and let us know (edit the output into the original question).

Comment: Your system should definitely be able to copy bigger files to USB, If you have FAT32, max file size is 4 GiB. It could be worth testing with a live system (booted from a USB drive with Ubuntu). This way you can check if there something wnet wrong in your installed system. You can also remove all other USB devices, and try in different USB ports. You can also try in other computers (with their operating systems and with your Ubuntu USB boot drive). This way you can try to find out if the problem is in the computer, in the pendrive or in the installed or live operating system.